# Why am I getting this time data does not match format error?

Tags: python, datetime

The original text I'm parsing is Sep 12, 2014 15:26:47 MDT

Since parsing the timezone doesn't work, I remove it by using this

```
d = " ".join(input.split()[:-1])
```

and then try to convert it to a datetime object with this

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")
```

but I keep getting this error:

time data 'Sep 12, 2014 15:26:47' does not match format '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S'

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha %I gets you the 12-hour hour (in your example, 03).

You need to use %H

```
 d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Worth bookmarking this page:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Ah, yes.  Thanks for including the explanation.  I was also parsing another string which included the 12-hour time and overlooked that when I changed the code for this one.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:
`d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")` 
to 
`d = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")`